# SSL Error for wildcard subdomain certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have two SSL certificate one for *.sub.domain.com and one for *.domain.com.

I don't have issues with domain level wildcard certificate. Meaning https://www.domain.com & https://domain.com works fine with out any certificate errors.

But for the other one https://sub.domain.com gives certificate error(address miss match ) and https://www.sub.domain.com doesn't give any error.

Just another info both certificate are from the same provider.

Comment: Which SSL certificate are you offering up on the server https://sub.domain.com ?

Comment: Its *.sub.domain.com

Comment: That's your problem - wrong certificate.  `sub.domain.com` doesn't match `*.sub.domain.com`, but it does match `*.domain.com`.

Comment: thanks @MadHatter. But wildcard certificates will match up to one level from the left. I think as zakjan mentioned its probably SAN difference between two certificate.

Comment: Yes, but they won't match **nothing at all**.  Zakjan's point is that `domain.com` doesn't match `*.domain.com`, which is very true, and just as truly `sub.domain.com` doesn't match `*.sub.domain.com`.  It is true that in the bare domain case this is often handled by SANs, but in your case you have a wildcard certificate that **will** match `sub.domain.com` - all you need to do is use it.

Comment: Okay got it. But if want to support both http://www.sub.doman.com & http://sub.domain.com then I will have to go for a new cert I guess.

Comment: No, I think you just need to make sure that on any given server instance, you offer the appropriate certificate.  You've told us nothing about your web server setup, so it's hard to be more specific.  Are you using SNI?

Comment: @MadHatter, you are correct I just want to make sure I have the proper SAN's added so that I can just use one certificate

Comment: You can't do this with one certificate.  I know of no certificating authority that will issue a double-wildcard certificate, valid for both `*.domain.com` and `*.sub.domain.com`.  I'm not even sure it's technically possible to do so, though I'm no expert on these matters.

Comment: May be even I am not sure but will try to my luck with CA this April. Between google.com has all sorts of combinations just in one certificate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wildcard certificate issued for `*.domain.com` doesn't secure bare `domain.com` by default.

Run `openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -noout -text` on both certs to see their human-readable content. Look for `X509v3 Subject Alternative Name` (SAN) field. If it is present, it specifies multiple DNS names, which can be secured by the cert.

I suppose your `*.domain.com` cert has it, whereas `*.sub.domain.com` doesn't, in that case ask for a new wildcard SAN cert.

Comment: Just checked that *.domain.com has domain.com as well but the subdomain certificate just have wildcard.

Comment: Instead of paying for a new cert, you can use `*.domain.com` to secure `sub.domain.com` as mentioned by @MadHatter, of course.